# Which version of Wicket runs on J2SE 1.4?

Tags: java, wicket

I would like to use Wicket on my new project but my client is still stuck to J2SE 1.4. Which version of Wicket runs on J2SE 1.4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wicket 1.4 depends on generics, and requires Java 1.5.  I think for Java 1.4, you'd be ok with Wicket 1.3.7, which is the last release below 1.4.

Answer (score 2):

Run away or persuade your client to upgrade... Java 1.4 is ancient and as far as I know no longer supported. Even support for Java 5 is waning. Java 6 has 30% performance gain over Java 5. You get that for free!

Using Wicket 1.3.7 is fine, but you will not be able to use much of the ecosystem that is built around Wicket 1.4.x, like the Wicket Stuff projects or WiQuery. The support around Wicket 1.3 has moved on to 1.4.x which has been around for about 2 years now.

Comment: +1 We should definitely try to eliminate obsolete technology.